# How to I get the innerHTML of the closest H3 from the clicked element?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="profile">
  <h3 class="name">Bob Chester</h3>
  <div class="position">Janitor</div>
  <div class="action">
    <a class="bio-click" href="/url/to/bio">Click Here For Bio</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to capture the name of the closest clicked URL into a JS variable. In this case, if you clicked the "Click Here For Bio" url, the variable would capture "Bob Chester".

What is the best way to go about that? I am creating a tracking label that I would like to return "Bob Chester - Bio Click" or something along those lines when they click on the url.

Comment: and what did you try?

Comment: _"if you clicked the "Click Here For Bio" url, the variable would capture "Bob Chester""_ - This expected result doesn't match the title at all...

Comment: "Capture" how, exactly?  The link implies that the user is being directed to another page.  Is that not what's happening here?

Comment: Apologies, I made a typo. The name is currently an h3 and I made it a div by mistake. Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this

closest is the keyword

Here I delegate from the nearest static container. Your container will be different, so change `document.getElementById("container")` to a relevant container

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("bio-click")) { // did we click a link?
    e.preventDefault(); // stop click  - remove this if you want the link to work
    const name = tgt.closest(".profile").querySelector(".name").textContent;
    console.log(name); // your method here
  }  
})
```

```html
<div id="container">

<div class="profile">
  <div class="name">Hannibal Lector</div>
  <div class="position">Serial killer</div>
  <div class="action">
    <a class="bio-click" href="/url/to/bio">Click Here For Bio</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="profile">
  <div class="name">Bob Chester</div>
  <div class="position">Janitor</div>
  <div class="action">
    <a class="bio-click" href="/url/to/bio">Click Here For Bio</a>
  </div>
</div>

</dov>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!